# How to delete "cancel" button when you use the segue on watchkit?

Tags: segue, watchkit

I want to implement the following function. 
1, click one from table object. 
2, display page based interface controller without the “cancel” button in the top left corner.

I think this function is implemented in Apple workout app.
In other words, you choose a workout like running from table object, and move pages to page-based interface controller without cancel button on left-top corner.
I want to know how to implement it.

This is my code:

```
override func table(_ table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAt rowIndex: 
Int) 
{  
    presentController(withNames: ["left", "Main", "Right"], contexts: [rowIndex])  
}
```

However, the "cancel" button was still present.

Please teach me how to implement this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this method you will get your desired pages without the "cancel" button at the top.  `WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames(["NewInterfaceController"], contexts: ["NewInterfaceController"])`

Replace "new interface controller" with the name of the interface controller you desire to present.